# TB mega menu does not work anymore

Tags: theming

I'm working with the *TB mega menu* module. Two days ago it worked perfectly; now I have this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function libraries_get_path() in
>   C:\wamp\www\drupal\sites\all\modules\tb_megamenu\tb_megamenu.admin.inc
>   on line 45

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[libraries_get_path()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!libraries!libraries.module/function/libraries_get_path/7) is provided by the [Libraries module](https://drupal.org/project/libraries). That error indicates that the Libraries module is either missing or not enabled.

Comment: yeah, i did not install it properly (as module)
thanks